# проблемы с bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

здравствуйте, к примеру есть обычный тэг `<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>` но дело в том что при удалении его, это делается нажатием на кнопку которая находится внутри блока, то подсказка остается на экране до перезагрузки страницы. я в принципе понимаю как можно это исправить, но неужели этот просчёт так и должен быть в бустрап клиенте?

Comment: Приведите больше кода. Неясно что где удаляется и внутри какого блока)

Comment: <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a> - обычная ссылка, если сделать её .remove() на jquery, во время наведения, подсказка останется на экране до ф5 страницы

Comment: Попробуйте в качестве контейнера для тултипа использовать, например, body: <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" data-container="body">Hover over me</a>

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, у кого будет данная проблема, нужно просто при удалении блока, удалять $(div).next(.tooltip) и всё, ибо сам он не пропадет.

Comment: Есть тег. Удалять то собственно что?